# Effect and Affect

Tags: differences

The new equipment had a positive effect on the business.

The new equipment had a positive affect on the business.

Am I right in saying that the top sentence has the correct use of effect/affect and the bottom one is incorrect?

Thank you for any help you are able to give.

Answer (score 1):

From grammarist:
"Affect is usually a verb, and effect is usually a noun. To affect something is to change or influence it, and an effect is something that happens due to a cause. When you affect something, it produces an effect. Here are a few examples of the words used correctly in these senses:

The storm knocked down power lines, affecting several thousand people in rural communities. [CBC]

Gauging the disaster’s effect requires assessing economic activity that might be lost. [Wall Street Journal]

The regulator has estimated that its new rules will affect up to 11.3pc of borrowers. [Telegraph]

But the smell of freshly baked bread may have positive effects far beyond the obvious ones. [Independent Online]"

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Hello, Misneac. This question has been asked here more than once before: please check obvious candidates before answering. Probably, it should have been closed in the first place, as being inappropriate for ELU.